# HTTP request body returning empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, http

When I create an HTTP request using my app, `req.body` is `{}`, but if I use Postman, `req.body` contains the correct information. I've looked at multiple Stack Overflow posts, but none of them have solved the problem. I would really appreciate any help I can get. Please let me know if I need to post more of my code.

I am using `app.use(express.json())`

Here is my front-end code:

```
fetch('/create-url', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        id: 'foo',
        url: 'bar',
    }),
    redirect: 'follow'
})
```

Here is my back-end code (which is also hosted on Firebase Functions):

```
app.post('/create-url', async (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I just tried to access localhost:5000 on Chrome and Edge and it refused to load (kept loading), but when I try it on Firefox, the page loaded. I don't know what's wrong and am really exasperated :(

Comment: Does your setup require CORS? Did you verify in the devtools network panel that the request is sent as expected?

Comment: When using Postman are you sending as `application/json` also, or form-encoded ?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure how to check the CORS settings in the devtools network panel, but I am using ```const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});``` and ```app.use(cors)```

Comment: @charlietfl Postman is sending the request as ```application/json```. I even tried running the code that Postman gave me from my app, and it still didn't work :(